# Using ignore.conf with logwatch

Tags: linux, log-files, logwatch

I have added the following to **/etc/postfix/header_checks** so that postfix will log the subject lines of every email:

```
/^subject: /    WARN
```

This produces log entries in **/var/log/mail.log** like:

```
May 19 07:10:48 server postfix/cleanup[1737]: 12E9DB13A3: warning: header Subject: Test Message; from=<www-data@server.domain>
```

And my **logwatch report** contains:

```
Header content warning (but passed): 1 Reason(s), 2030 time(s)
```

I have put both of the following in my **/etc/logwatch/conf/ignore.conf**, but they do not seem to avoid this message:

```
warning: header Subject:
Header content warning (but passed): 1 Reason(s)
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second attempt in **/etc/logwatch/conf/ignore.conf** is correct, except that **the brackets need to be escaped**.  Adding a backslash before each bracket caused logwatch to correctly ignore the lines.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the records: logwatch uses Perl style regexes in ignore.conf. So look at

```
$ man 1 perlre
```